# SharePoint online domain name

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft365

We have a SharePoint Online site https://mycompany1.sharepoint.com in prod tenant which is being used by Teams.
We are planning to migrate our on-prem SharePoint 2016 sites to SPO.
Can i able to use a different domain (https://mycompany2.sharepoint.com) within the same subscription for production?

Thanks
Venky

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge,you cannot use a different domain within the same subscription for production.